# Google Place Picker not launching on some phones

Tags: android, google-places-api

We are facing an issue with Google Place Picker that it is not launching on one particular phone (MI Note 4 running Android 6.0) and raises exception an dialog, "Unfortunately, Google Play service...".

1) Code is working on all the test phones we have, around 20 different models from Gingerbread to Nougat except this phone. Hence, the permission and key do not appear to be issue. com.google.android.geo.API_KEY is properly placed in application section.

2) The issue is particularly happening with this phone only. Google play service is installed on the phone and calling *GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable* returns *ConnectionResult.SUCCESS* as expected, which we check before launching place picker.

3) Also, the phone has play store, & Google map runs fine which further confirms play service is working.

4) We even tried downgrading google play API to 10.0.1 and 9.2.0 just to find the cause but behaviour is the same.

Below is the code, it's a standard place-picker code.

```
try {
     PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
     Intent intent = builder.build(this);
     startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
 } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
     GooglePlayServicesUtil
                    .getErrorDialog(e.getConnectionStatusCode(), this, 0);
 } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services is not available.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 } catch (Exception e) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services exception.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Are there any exceptions logged in logcat that you could post?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is occurring due to Google services. Google services need to be updated. So just put a check before opening your app or place picker.

```
if (googlePlayApiStatus == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED)
```

If returns true. Show a dialog to user to update Google services and paste below code to take user to Google play store to update services.

```
final String appPackageName = "com.google.android.gms";
try {
/*IT WILL OPEN IN GOOGLE PLAY STORE*/
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
/*IF GOOGLE PLAY STORE APP NOT FOUND IN DEVICE IT WILL OPEN IN WEB BROWSER*/
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
```

That's it !!